# componentWillMount for react functional component?

Tags: reactjs, react-chartjs, react-functional-component

For react class component, we have the **componentWillMount()** lifecycle method, where we can perform tasks before loading the component. Tasks like, a call to backend and use the response to show that data in that frontend.

What if I want the same thing in a functional component? Like I have used react chartJS and for that the data values I want to be retrieved from backend response, and then the chart will populate based on those datas.

Comment: 1) [`componentWillMount` has been deprecated](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount) and should not be used even in class components. 2). You're looking for [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

Comment: The best you can do is emulate `componentDidMount` by using an empty dependency array for `useEffect`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`componentWillMount` is call only one time before initial render.
I make a sample code, check it out below

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false)

  if(!mounted){
    // Code for componentWillMount here
    // This code is called only one time before intial render
  }

  useEffect(() =>{
    setMounted(true)
  },[])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      
    </div>
  );
}
```

- As you mentioned you want to make an api call, it usually happen in `componentDidmount` and you can simply use `useEffect` hook with empty array as dependencies in functional component

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false)


  useEffect(() =>{
    // This is similar to componentDidMount
    // Call back-end api here
  },[])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: And it's not like linter such a condition wouldn't let go because you can't do hooks conditionally? It's an antipattern according to the documentation from what I remember.

Answer (score 8):

Actually, I want to add more cases here, and I am going to make reusable custom hooks.

#### 1.Care about extra dom render

**It will not cause extra dom render**

```
const useOptimizedComponentWillMount = callback => {
  const mounted = useRef(false)
  if (!mounted.current) callback()

  useEffect(() => {
    mounted.current = true
  }, []);
};
```

> Note: You might want `mounted && mounted.current` in typescript

#### 2. Don't care about extra dom render

> this is exactly [Tony answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62091261/10321531)

```
const useComponentWillMount = callback => {
  const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false)
  if (!mounted) callback()

  useEffect(() => {
    setMounted(true)
  }, [])
};
```

#### Usage

```
const App = () => {
  useComponentWillMount(() => console.log("will mount"))
  return console.log("render-dom") || <div>Layout</div>
};
// will mount
// (2)render-dom
```

```
const App = () => {
  useOptimizedComponentWillMount(() => console.log("will mount"))
  return console.log("render-dom") || <div>Layout</div>
};
// will mount
// render-dom
```