# ReactJS - run once on component mount but before return

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am looking to have something run once when the react app first loads and only the one time. At first, one is inclined to make use of the `useEffect` hook:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Effect hook.");
  }, []);
```

The problem with this approach is that when I put it in my `App` component, the `useEffect` hook runs **AFTER** mounting. Subsequently, the following will fail because stuff won't be defined when the child component renders:

```js
function App() {

  let stuff;

  // Define the supported configs on mount. This will only run at mount time.
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Effect hook.");
    stuff = getSomeStuff();
  }, []); 

  //

  console.log("About to return.");
  return (
    <div>
      <ComponentThatNeedsStuff stuff={stuff} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

and you will see the following printed:

```
About to return.
Effect hook.
```

If you only want the function `getSomeStuff` to run once but you need the stuff for child components, what is the best way to handle that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [componentWillMount for react functional component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62091146/componentwillmount-for-react-functional-component)

Comment: Not quite because I'm using state for other things - it's not clear to me how I would integrate the above. I may change how I do this entirely based on feedback coming in as it seems there are multiple alternatives, but `useMemo` as mentioned below in @Nicholas Tower's answer accomplished what I set out to do with this question.

Answer (score 4):

Running code **before** render is usually a sign that you’re going against the grain of how React works.

```js
const App = () => {
  const [stuff, setStuff] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Effect hook.");
    setStuff(getSomeStuff());
  }, []); 


  return (
    <div>
      {stuff && <ComponentThatNeedsStuff stuff={stuff} />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: What is the correct way to do  this? In my case, I have several supported configs I want to read into memory once and then pass to the child. Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: I'm usually use NextJS and if that only configs i would define a .env file for that (react: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/) otherwise i declare the config outside the App component.

Comment: Now that I'm playing around with the options - the only downside to the main answer above is that in my live app I'm using routing. Apologies, I didn't include it in my snippit as I didn't think it would be relevant, but it seems like this doesn't work with routing because the element won't be defined? I'm a bit of a neophyte so I may be missing something. I'll check out the linked doc.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a job for [useMemo](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/useMemo). It lets you do a calculation during rendering, but then on later renders it can skip the calculation and reuse the previous value:

```
function App() {
  const stuff = useMemo(() => {
    return getSomeStuff();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <ComponentThatNeedsStuff stuff={stuff} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I'll leave things open since there seems to be some good discussion and maybe I should be doing this differently but this was exactly the behavior I wanted. Thanks! Learned about a new hook today.